# Why isn't awk summing column in .tsv file from Distrokid?

Tags: bash, csv, awk

Here's my code:

`awk -F ' ' '{sum+=$7} END {print sum}' file.tsv`

Works just fine on most of my .tsv files. On .tsv files from Distrokid, code doesn't work. Just returns 0. Experimenting, it appears to only return the value of the first entry in the column. Oddly, if I copy the contents of the .tsv file to a new file and save that as a .tsv, it then works. Please find links to 2 .tsv files. One works, the other does not. Why is this?

[WORKS](https://madeincomputer.com/WORKS.tsv)

[DOESNT WORK](https://madeincomputer.com/DOESNT_WORK.tsv)

Comment: do a `cat` on those two files and show us how the data looks in those files

Answer (score 1):

Your other file has no Unix line breaks. It only has `\r` (DOS line ending).

This `gnu awk` command will work for both the input files:

```
awk -v RS='[\r\n]+' '{sum += $8} END{print sum}' DOESNT_WORK.tsv
```

```
28200
```

`-v RS='[\r\n]+'` is using **input record separator** as one or more of `\r` or `\n` characters.

Comment: A `\r` line ending was used by pre OS X Macs. DOS used `\r\n` just like Windows.